# Why is my munin plugin being double executed (concurrently)?

Tags: monitoring, munin, system-monitoring

I have a custom made munin plugin that currently is being executed twice every time

```
$ ps fax
16844 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/munin-node
18206 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/munin-node
18863 ?        Ss     0:00  |   \_ /bin/bash /etc/munin/plugins/fetch_partner 
18910 ?        S      0:00  |       \_ wget -q -O /tmp/partner_debug_page.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /tmp/partne
18209 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/munin-node
18892 ?        Ss     0:00      \_ /bin/bash /etc/munin/plugins/fetch_partner 
18917 ?        S      0:00          \_ wget -q -O /tmp/partner_debug_page.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /tmp/partne
```

According to the munin-node log there are no timeouts happening. According to munin master it is graphing this plugin twice every time (arround 20 seconds inbetween those graphs, so I guess it's from each fetch).

Does anyone know why this is happening? It looks funny that /usr/sbin/munin-node is being called twice...

Answer (score 1):

Munin runs each plugin twice per (five minute) cycle: once to get the configuration, and a second time to get the plugin's values.

http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToWritePlugins

Comment: Yes, I know this. But this is not the case this time. As you can see above my Munin script is called twice simultaneously every five minutes. Both invokations are done without the config parameter.

The script is also invoked with the config parameter once every 5 minutes, but when "config" is given it exits immediately and does not invoke wget.